# How to display a picture on UIView programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I want to ask a question about the UIview on the iPhone applicaiton. I want to display a image one the UIView programmatically, but I don't know how to do it. What should I do to display the image. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use UIImageView. It is a subclass of UIView and you can set the image with an instance on UIImage.

Here is an example to add it to another UIView.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameofimage.png"]];
[myUIView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an image to your project e.g. Spinner.png

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Spinner" ofType: @"png"];
NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy just assign [CGImageRef](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgimageref) to view's layer's content, eg:

```
layerView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "Mario.png")?.cgImage
```